# Proof that $\ell^p$ has empty interior in $\ell^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Let $p\in [1,2)$. I want to prove that $\ell^p$ has empty interior in $\ell^2$.

Let me first remark that if $Y$ is a subspace of a normed space $X$ s.t. $Y\neq X$ then if we pick $x\in X$ we can define $x_n=x+\frac{1}{n}x_0$ where $x_0\in X\setminus Y$, then clearly $x_n\in X\setminus Y$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$, therefore $\overline{X\setminus Y}=X$.

Now if we take $X=\ell^2$ and $Y=\ell^p$ then we deduce from the remark that $\ell^2\setminus \ell^p$ is dense in $\ell^2$. But this means that $\ell^p$ is nowhere dense in $\ell^2$. So $\ell^p \cap \{x\in \ell^2: ||x-y||_2<r\}=\emptyset$ where $y\in \ell^2$, $r>0$. This means that $\ell^p$ does not contain any open balls and hense $\ell^p$ has empty interior in $\ell^2$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks for your input but I would like to know if my argumentation is correct

Comment: Why is $x_n \in X\setminus Y$?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic because if $x_n\in Y$ for all $n$ then this would mean $x_0\in Y$